# Capybara unable to find form field with correct ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, capybara, rspec-rails

I'm trying to use capybara to simulate a login to test my login form, however it cannot find the email or password fields.

I have checked the page source to confirm that I am using the right ID, and I have also tried using the field names.

Here is my current test:

```
it "returns http success" do
      user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      visit sessions_new_path
      fill_in 'email', :with => user.email
      fill_in 'password', :with => user.password
      click_button('submit')
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
    end
```

My form:

```
= form_for(:session, url: login_path, :html => {class: 'login_form'}) do |f|
    .field
      = f.email_field :email, 'data-msg-required' => t('email_required'), :placeholder => t('.form_email'), id: 'email'
    .field
      = f.password_field :password, 'data-msg-required' => t('password_required'), :placeholder => t('.form_pwd'), id: 'password'
    = f.submit t('.form_sbmt'), class: 'btn-submit'
```

When viewing the page source the IDs are listed as email and password (for the respective fields), and the names follow the format "session[email]". I've tried using "sessions[email]" (and equiv for password) for fill_in but had no luck.

Error I'm getting:

```
Failure/Error: fill_in 'email', :with => user.email

     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find field "email"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capybara isn't used in controller tests. Capybara is used for end-to-end testing of your app (feature tests) and isn't limited to just testing the controller.  The controller test for your action should be something like

```
it "returns http success" do
  user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  post :create, session: { email: user.email, password: user.password}
  expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
end
```

which will be very quick and have no need to render the views.

Answer (score 0):

<s>So I found the answer. I didn't realise Rspec does not render views when running controller tests (as it expects views to be tested separately). In order to get the controller tests to render a view you just need to add `renders_view` within one of your describe-do blocks (but NOT inside the it-do block).</s>

Seems my tests are now working.

Not really a suitable answer as discussed in the comments.

Comment: You shouldn't be using Capybara in controller test, it's for use in feature tests (and the marchers in view test)

Comment: I realise that, but I didn't know how else to test my session's create action. When I tried posting create I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: It sounds like you're testing the wrong things in your controller tests.  If you want to do full controller/view/routing tests they should be feature tests - if you are writing a controller test then it should only be testing the variables that are set by, and the response from the controller action. In your example a controller test should basically just be something like  `post :create, session: { email: user.email, password: user.password} ;  expect(response)...`

Comment: Okay, I understand what you're saying. I removed the tests from my controller and tried the test using the post you suggested and it worked. So if you wanna post it as an answer I'd be happy to mark it as the answer. Thanks very much!